# How to retrieve text value from input-tag element?

Tags: selenium

I need to retreive phone number from the UI element which looks like this:

[image]

And here is the HTML-code of this element:

```
<label class="card__phone input">
    <input class="input__text ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-valid-mask ng-not-empty" ng-model="person.msisdn" ui-mask="+9 (999) 999-9999" disabled="" placeholder="+_ (___) ___-____" type="text">
</label>
```

As you can see, we do not have a phone number data in this element, just format. I've tried to find the number using **.//*[contains(text(), '+7 (921) 222-3344')]** XPATH search - no results.

Forntend engeneers use Angular JS to build current web-app.

Comment: Did you use gettext?

Comment: Could you share tried selenium code as well for getting this text??

Comment: Kishan, yes, I've used getText()

Comment: Saurbh, the part of code looks like: String xpath = "//*[@id='mCSB_2_container']/li[1]/ng-include/div/ng-include/div[1]/label/input";
        WebElement e = app.getWebDriver().findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
        String phoneNum = e.getText();
        assertThat(phoneNum, equalTo("+7 (944) 222-33-44"));

Comment: Result is Expected :+7 (944) 222-33-44
Actual   :

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer is to getAttribute("value"), from the WebElement.